# Cannot create a FIFO SQS through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

I'm trying to create a FIFO using the CLI, But I get an error

```
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue.fifo --attributes FifoQueue=true --region us-east-1

An error occurred (InvalidAttributeName) when calling the CreateQueue operation: Unknown Attribute FifoQueue.
```

[The doc page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/create-queue.html) says that this is a valid attribute. What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SQS FIFO queues are one of the rare services that weren't available in N. Virginia on launch.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-sqs-introduces-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-processing-and-lower-prices-for-standard-queues/

> FIFO queues are now available in the US East (Ohio) and US West (Oregon) regions, with more regions to follow.

Try running the command in one of the supported regions.

Ohio:

```
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue.fifo --attributes FifoQueue=true --region us-east-2
```

Oregon:

```
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue.fifo --attributes FifoQueue=true --region us-west-2
```

**Update:** Nowadays, North Virginia has support for FIFO SQS Queues.

Answer (score 3):

SQS Queue has two different types.
1) Standard Queue
2) Fifo Queue

if you are using a standard queue, try running the command for creating a queue.

```
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name <<queue-name>> --attributes VisibilityTimeout=900
```

if you are using a Fifo queue, try running the command for creating a queue.

- The name of a FIFO queue must end with the .fifo suffix. The suffix counts towards the 80-character queue name quota. To determine whether a queue is FIFO, you can check whether the queue name ends with the suffix.
- Designates a queue as FIFO. Valid values: true, false. If you don't specify the FifoQueue attribute, Amazon SQS creates a standard queue. You can provide this attribute only during queue creation. You can't change it for an existing queue. When you set this attribute, you must also provide the MessageGroupId for your messages explicitly.
- Attributes must be in the string.

`aws sqs create-queue --queue-name queue-name.fifo --region us-east-1 --attributes  "{\"FifoQueue\":\"true\", \"VisibilityTimeout\":\"900\"}"`